# Why if I change (.hamburger > div > position: fixed) the hamburger becoming so long (bigger than parent's width)?

Tags: position, width, css-position

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Showcase */
.showcase{
    background-color: rgba(25, 45, 200, 0.6);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
.showcase::after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/533923/pexels-photo-533923.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center/cover;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
}
/* Showcase */

/* Menu */
.main-menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 40px;
}

.input{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

/* Hamburger */
.hamburger{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
.hamburger > div{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
.hamburger > div::before,
.hamburger > div::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.hamburger > div::after{
    top: 10px;
}

/* Hamburger */
.menu{
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Menu */
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
    <input type='checkbox' class="input">
    <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Support</li>
            <li>Feedback</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="showcase"></div>
```

I was surprised when I changed `.hamburger > div > position: fixed` (from `relative`). The hamburger is becoming so long (somewhere 900px although its parent from which width is inherited has only 40px width). I understand that it is connected with the position by why so long (even longer than its parent)?

Comment: Why do you want position fixed in that element? what you want to achive?

Comment: I don't want the position to be fixed. By accident while writing the code I noticed this strange for my situation and want to clarify it for myself.
My goal is to understand - why the element's width with position "fixed" is more than parent's one.